# Ajaxfileupload not working when dropdownlist is place inside an updatepanel in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload

When the page is loaded I have no problem using the ajaxfileupload and selecting files for the upload.
This works perfectly until I select a value of the first dropdownlist and the second dropdownlist inside the updatepanel gets populated via the partial postback. From this event on, the select button of the ajaxfileupload control is without function. 
Is this a bug or how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `dropdown`'s ID in `PostBackTrigger` of the update panel.

**update:**

```
<UpdatePanel ID="upd1">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" onselectedIndexChanged="ddl_changed" />
</UpdatePanel>

<UpdatePanel ID="upd2">
    <Ajax:FileUploader />
</UpdatePanel>

protected void ddl1_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code

    upd2.Update();
}
```

This might help you :)

Comment: Hi Avishek using <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" /> works fine but I want my dropdownlist to do a partial postback with <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" />

Comment: @Jack : can you put the `file-uploader` inside the `updatepanel` ?

Comment: @Jack : there is one more thing you can do to prevent full-postback. put the `file-uploader` into another `updatepanel` **upd2**, and at end of the `drop-downchange` event, write `upd2.Update()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but can you please show me with some code. I am confused my AjaxFileUpload was already placed inside another UpdatePanel and DropDownList inside another UpdatePanel

Comment: Man Avishek how can you be brilliant. I wish I have your brain. thanks you so much